# comparing date time logic

Tags: javascript, date, logic

I have looked through other asked questions but havn't found the issue with my code exactly.
I am trying to find the newer of  2 dates, and i have split the DD,MM YY,HH,MM,SS into variables so i can do the following and compare

```
    var bool = false
   if (year1 <= year2)
       if (month1 <= month2)
           if (day1 <= day2)
               if (hours1 <= hours2)
                   if (minutes1 <= minutes2)
                       if (seconds1 <= seconds2)
                           bool = true;
 return bool;
```

However, I still run into issue if for example the first date is less in Day month and year and hour, but greater in minutes and seconds

ex:
if time 1 is 18/7/2016 15:16:4  and time 2 is 19/7/2016 18:14:59

it would result in a false even though time 2 is newer, it just the seconds thats an issue.
can this be fixed by else ?

Comment: Why do not do just: `if (year1 <= year2 && month1 <= month2 && day1 <= day2 && hours1 <= hours2 && minutes1 <= minutes2 && seconds1 <= seconds2) {
  bool = true;
 }`?

Comment: Why split the date in fields to begin with, rather than using the native comparison operators on `Date` objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: initially i started with that, but in favour of optimization i thought the way i did with multiple if's might better?

Comment: This is premature optimization. Don't go out of your way to optimize until you need it : the time you might gain in computation speed might be shadowed by the time you might loss in maintaining more complex code.

Comment: "in favour of optimization"... so all of the logic to extract out different parts of the date and create 12 variables and use 6 comparison operators is more "optimized" than creating 2 date objects, calling getTime() on each of them, and doing a single comparison?

Comment: @mhodges—parsing a string to date is 2 lines of code, the date comparison (no need for *getTime*) is one.

Answer (score 1):

For your question: *I am trying to find the newer of 2 dates*

I can suggest to use `getTime()` function.

Will be able to compare time by ticks.

Let's consider you have `date1` and `date2`. `date1` is 2015-06-10 15:20:30 and `date2` is 2016-06-10 16:30:50

`date1.getTime()` will be smaller than `date2.getTime()`

**date1**

`Human time (GMT): Wed, 10 Jun 2015 15:20:03 GMT
Epoch timestamp: 1433949603
Timestamp in milliseconds: 1433949603000`

**date2**

`Human time (GMT): Fri, 10 Jun 2016 16:30:50 GMT
Epoch timestamp: 1465576250
Timestamp in milliseconds: 1465576250000`

[example here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

[convertor here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

---

**Update:**
Bellow is an example of function:

```
// returns true if date1 is newer than date2 and false viceversa
function compareForNewer(date1, date2) {
    return date1.getTime() > date2.getTime();
}
```

Or, you can return always the newer date. As follows:

```
// returns the newer date
function getNewer(date1, date2) {
    return date1.getTime() > date2.getTime() ? date1 : date2;
}
```

Hope it will help you. Enjoy!

Comment: @user3676224 I added examples of functions ;) Good luck!

Comment: There is no need for *getTime*, `date1 > date2` is sufficient since the `>` operator coerces the arguments to Number, and that returns the Date's internal time value, the same as *getTime* does.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers here to questions about parsing, the bottom line is that you can write a bespoke function in a few lines, but likely it's better to get a small parsing and formatting library to do the job. There are plenty of those, such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), [date.js](http://www.datejs.com) and [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).

For example, using fecha.js and assuming an input format like 18/7/2016 15:16:40 that should be treated as local, you'd do a *getEarliest* function something like:

```
/* Convert args to Dates, return earliest as a Date
** or first as a date if they are equal.
** requires fecha.js https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha
**
** @param {string} dateStr0 - date string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss format
** @param {string} dateStr1 - date string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss format
** @returns {Date} earliest of dateStr0 and dateStr1 or dateStr0 if equal
*/
function getEarliest(dateStr0, dateStr1) {
  var d0 = fecha.parse(dateStr0, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
  var d1 = fecha.parse(dateStr1, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
  return d1 < d0? d1 : d0; 
}
```

Without a general parser, you can use a function like the following and use it to replace the parsing bit. You should also test the result of parsing to make sure it created a valid Date:

```js
/* Parse string in format DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss
** @param {string} s - date string in format DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss
** @returns {Date} if values invalid, returns invalid Date
*/
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
  return d && d.getMinutes() == b[4] && d.getDate() == b[0] && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

/* Convert args to Dates, return earliest as a Date
** or first as a date if they are equal.
** If either date is invalid, returns undefined
**
** @param {string} dateStr0 - date string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss format
** @param {string} dateStr1 - date string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss format
** @returns {Date} earliest of dateStr0 and dateStr1 or 
**                 dateStr0 if equal or
**                 undefined if either is invalid
*/
function getEarliest(dateStr0, dateStr1) {
  var d0 = parseDate(dateStr0);
  var d1 = parseDate(dateStr1);
  if (isNaN(d0) || isNaN(d1)) return;
  return d1 < d0? d1 : d0; 
}

// Both valid dates
console.log(getEarliest('15/08/2016 15:23:48', '18/08/2016 17:25:08'))

// One date invalid
console.log(parseDate('15/08/2016 15:73:48', '18/08/2016 17:25:08'))
```